# Find And Get Data In Datagridview With Condition / Statement in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, datagridview, find, where-clause

How to Fnd and Get Data in Datagridview with COndition / Statement in VB.Net?
This the ilustration.

Let's Say The Table Below A Datagridview, with 5 Columns and 5 Rows.

[image]

Case In **S1**

The example of my problem, in S1 :

[1.] Check Ranking A = Ranking B?

> **[NO]**

[2.] Find Ranking B that have Value = Ranking A!

> **Row-2 [S2]**

[3.] Take Nilai B in the Row-2!

> **[0.8]**

[4.] Find the difference between Nilai B in S1 and S2

> **[0.8 – 0.9 = 0.1]**

[5.] Add new Columns and Put 0.1 right there.

And The Result Will be like this :

[image]

I dont Understand about Step 2 and Step 3, Somebody please Help Me! I’m confuse because there is no **WHERE** in VB.Net to make Condition!

Comment: Did you here about LINQ to objects? I think you can use it in your case [LINQ Query Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688084)

Comment: LINQ like Query in Database?

Comment: Do you have a datasource?

Comment: Then why are you doing it backwards? This is what SQL was designed for. The primary goal of a DataGridView is to display data.

Comment: Hehehehe.. Can you give me an example, how to do this with Query? Pleaseeee..

Comment: No I can't, because the `DataGridView` doesn't support these kinds of things.

Comment: I think their is a way to set filters to your datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Use datagridview filters like this:

```
 YourGridViewBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("YourDBColumn Like ;'*" & FilterValue) & "*'"
```

Also you can take `yourYourGridViewBindingSource`
If it's `datatable` or `dataset` and use:

```
  Datasource.select(your conditions)
```